# build from hadoop source code in centos

Tags: hadoop

can anyone guide me to build hadoop from source code(using git) in linux centos

i have install centos v-6 in virtual box .I have imported the source code from github and given the following commands

clean install -DskipTests
  $ mvn package -Pdist -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
  mvn package -Pdist,native,docs -DskipTests -Dtar
  $ mvn package -Psrc -DskipTests
  mvn package -Pdist,native,docs,src -DskipTests -Dtar

i have installed protocol buffer and all the required softwares..

Please guide in deploying as well as debugging of the code

Comment: Did you check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463763/how-do-i-build-hadoop-from-source-without-errors

Comment: yes.after building  i got success message ..from their if i issue start-all.sh i am getting namenode unknown host exception.Please guide